# Is a conditional expectation with two conditioning variables equal to zero?

Tags: probability

**Question:** Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three random variables on the same probability space. If $E(X|Y) = 0$ and $E(X|Z) = 0$, does it necessarily follow that $E(X|Y,Z) = 0$?

**Discussion:** I thought this would be easy to demonstrate with the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), but that only seems to imply that $E(E(X|Y,Z)) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, try $(Y,Z)$ independent and centered and $X=YZ$. Then $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)=Y\mathbb E(Z)=0$ and $\mathbb E(X\mid Z)=Z\mathbb E(Y)=0$ but $\mathbb E(X\mid Y,Z)=YZ$ which is not zero in general.

Indeed, $\mathbb E(\mathbb E(X\mid Y,Z))=0$, always, since $\mathbb E(\mathbb E(X\mid Y,Z))=\mathbb E(X)$ and, by hypothesis, $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)=0$ hence $\mathbb E(X)=\mathbb E(\mathbb E(X\mid Y))=0$.

Comment: For example, take $Y$ to be a coin flip giving values $1$ and $-1$ equal probability, take $Z$ to be identical to $Y$ and independent, and take $X=YZ$.

Comment: @GregMartin No. Please do not take $Z$ "identical to" $Y$. If you wish, take $Z$ with the same distribution as $Y$, and independent.

Comment: Great counter-example +1. Thank you.

Comment: I agree that "identically distributed" is more accurate than "identical".